# Put one marker on top of all other markers on the map

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

I am using gmaps4rails to show bunch of markers that represent places of interest on the map. In addition I also show one "special" marker that represent accommodation. This marker has distinct icon and I would like it to always be shown on top of all other markers regardless of the zoom.

I have tried different ways but I can't manage to put the "special" marker on top. Now all the markers are shown on the map in correct places and with correct icons but the "special" one is not on top.

Could you please advise?

This is a snippet of the relevant code. I am trying to use zIndex but probably wrong.

```
   markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
   var zInd = markers.length;

    markers[zInd] = handler.addMarker(
    {
        lat: lat,
        lng: lng,
        picture: {
            url: "/images/hotel_icon.png",
            width:  50,
            height: 50
        },
        zIndex: zInd + 1
    });
```

Comment: Can you inspect the marker (in dev tools in whatever browser you use) and see what z-index is actually applied to the marker?  (and the same for the other markers).  Maybe your logic for setting zIndex is wrong.

Comment: when you zoom in, is the marker showing up at all?  If so, I would go off what @MaxWilliams says and either inspect it or set it to a really high number manually and see if it works.

Comment: Yes the marker is showing and with correct lat/lng and custom icon. The thing is that when I inspect marker object in the browser dev tools I don't see the zIndex field at all. The object has a lot of components in it so maybe I just don't know where to look. Setting zIndex in this code to a very high number doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [mentioned in the doc](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Js-Methods#handler-interface), options should be passed as a second argument:

```
markers[zInd] = handler.addMarker(
  {
    lat: lat,
    lng: lng,
    picture: {
      url: "/images/hotel_icon.png",
      width:  50,
      height: 50
    }
  },
  {
    zIndex: zInd + 1
  }
);
```